# Shopping districts in Beijing

Tags: shopping, beijing

Me and the wife will visit Beijing next month and we (well the wife mostly) would like to do some shopping.

What are the best shopping districts in Beijing?

We're not particularly looking for bargains, but more for the whole shopping experience. So bonus points for any place that has some nice cafes or benches for a much needed rest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wangfujing shopping street is the most famous for visitors--nice environment, adjacency to the Tian'anmen Square and Forbidden City, clean street bars, and backstreet traditional snack bars, etc.

Xidan shopping area is most popular for the local youth. There are quite some modern shopping malls with comfortable shopping environment.

Qianmen and Dashilan shopping streets are China's traditional shopping streets located to the south of Tian'anmen Square, and boast significant traditional buildings and time-honoured brands.

Other famous shopping areas include Lufthansa Tower (expensive imported goods and cafes), Guomao (International Trading Center) Shopping mall (very nice and top-end), Shin Kong Shopping Mall (nice boutiques and cafes), etc;

There are also featured shopping areas such as Yabao Road and Silk Street (bargain garments), Panjiayuan (antiques), etc.

wish you and your wife a nice shopping experience in Beijing :-)

Comment: +1 for Wanfujing, I visited it a lot when I was living there in 2005.

Answer (score 4):

I hope this article will help you http://www.travelchinaguide.com/cityguides/beijing/shopping.htm

You can also use these maps http://www.chinatouristmaps.com/shopping/beijing.html - it's really usefull. You may point out where the main shops is
[image: main shops in Beijing]

> **Largest Beijing Shopping Areas**
>
> - *Wangfujing Dajie* - the most famous shopping street in Beijing, starts from the East Chang'an Street and ends at China Art Museum.
> - *Qiananmen Dajie* - an ancient shopping street outside Qianmen Gate, famous for the Dashilar Tourist and Pedestrian Street.
> - *Xidan Commercial Area* - regarded as the second Wangfujing, is a favorite shopping area among locals, especially young people.
> - *Sanlitun Shopping Area* - Sanlitun is a very popular destination among foreign visitors mostly because of the bars, clubs and
>     restaurants of its bar street.
>
> **Antique Markets**
>
> - *Liulichang Antique Street* - antique stores, selling Chinese paintings, handicrafts, used books and other items. Located in
>     Xuanwumen, it lined with quite old stores. You may find some treasures
>     here.
> - *Panjiayuan Antique Market* - Panjiayuan Flea Market is your right choice with China's most comprehensive and largest collection and
>     distributing center of antique goods and handicrafts.
>
> **Theme Shopping Streets**
>
> - *Hongqiao Pearl Market* - Also known as the Pearl Market, the Hongqiao Market is the largest **pearl** distributing center in China.
>     There are varied kinds of pearls, including seawater pearl, freshwater
>     pearl, coral and so forth.
> - *Xiushui Silk Street* - Xiushui Market, famous for the **Chinese silk**, has reopened for business in a bright and spacious shopping
>     mall instead of the original outdoor Xiushui Street.
> - *Maliandao Tea Steet* - located in the southwestern part of Xuanwu District is the biggest **tea market** of north China and the most
>     famous tea street in Beijing.
> - *Laitai Flower Market* - Laitai Flower Market, also known as Ladies Street, is a component part of the Beijing Laitai Flower
>     Trading Center, along with Laitai Flower Auction Center and Laitai
>     Flower Street, and the largest **flower** center in north China.
> - *Zhongguancun Digital Paradise*- Zhongguancun, popularly known as China's Silicon Valley, is another busy area in Beijing, which is
>     jam-packed with people wanting to buy **electronics**.
> - *Gaobeidian Classic Furniture Street* - The Gaobeidian Classic Furniture Street is one of the best **antique furniture markets** in
>     Beijing.
> - *Nanluoguxiang Market* - Nanluoguxiang, one of the best preserved historical areas in downtown Beijing, is famous for its hutong and
>     siheyuan courtyards, as well as the bars, cafes, clothing and
>     handicraft shops there.

This site also describes all Beijing most famous places for shopping http://www.shoppinginbeijing.com/what_are_you_looking_for

Answer (score 1):

If you are into antiques (mostly fake ones) you can try LiuLiChang or PanJiaYuan Antique Market. It's fun to just browse or get something cheap but interesting, I'll definitely get a second opion  .